# C++: Dynamic array of user defined class

Tags: c++

I have tried this:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int * pn = new int[n];
```

Then I can use the array lik this: pn[i] = ...

But I would like to organize something of the kind with my own class:

```
class MyString
{
    char* m_pStr;
    public:
    MyString(const char* pStr){ 
        this->CreateArray(pStr);
        strcpy(m_pStr, pStr);
    }
}

void main(){
    int N;
    cout << "Iinput N: ";
    cin >> N;
    MyString * ar = new MyString[N];

    char tmp[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        cout <<"Input the string for the Mystring " << i + 1 << " ";
        cin >> tmp;     
        ar[i] = MyString(tmp);
    }
}
```

I get: error C2512: 'MyString' : no appropriate default constructor available.

Comment: Please read a Good Introductory book on C++. Here is few recommendations : [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: When you are using C++, NEVER use C-strings. Always use `string`. ALWAYS.

Comment: The very words in the error message couldn't possibly make it clearer what the problem is. `MyString` has no default constructor, and the code you wrote requires one. (and in truth, the code you wrote needs std::string and belay all the rest).

Comment: possible duplicate of [When do we need to have a default constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498937/when-do-we-need-to-have-a-default-constructor)

Comment: What is `CreateArray(...)`?

Comment: If you are going to ask for help please take time to format the code nicely. You are nor using C++ well here. You should prefer automatic objects to dynamic ones. If you don't know the difference a good book should be your next stop.

Comment: What you need to do is to read some basic books.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to instantiate the `MyString` class with the default constructor without having defined one in this line:

```
MyString * ar = new MyString[N];
```

It has to initialize the objects and will therefore try to use the default constructor that is not set.

I would personally change your constructor from:

```
MyString(const char* pStr);
```

to:

```
MyString(const char* pStr = "");
```

in order to act like the default one.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the **default constructor**!

```
MyString() : m_pStr(0) { }
```

That error occurred when you tried to instantiate the array of MyStrings from here:

```
MyString * ar = new MyString[N];
```

Which looks for a default constructor. Since you hadn't defined one in your class definition, you got the error that you described.

**Hence, to solve your problems, create default constructor for your class, and everything should compile as it should.**

See this link for more details (or read up on some C++):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is a lot that I would change in the code above.

First, the answer to your question: the default constructor is not always needed. In fact, if you do not define any constructor method, then the default constructor is invoked automatically. However, since you defined a constructor with arguments, then you need to define its behaviour. If you don't want it to be invoked in your code, define it under `private` in your class definition. Now, once you fix that, you are going to run into other problems:

1. `this` is a pointer to the current object, and you are trying to dereference it and get the member function `CreateArray`, which doesn't exist.
2. Never use C-style strings when coding in C++, because you can create `string` objects, and if you ever need the c-style string, you can retrieve it with a method of the `string` class called `c_str()`.
3. Don't use `void` main. Not all compilers allow it
4. Free the memory used by the dynamically created array, using `delete [] ar`

So, the code has a bunch of problems. I think the real issue here, is that you probably know some C, and you are rushing to learn C++, but please keep in mind that learning a language properly takes patience, and just because your code might work, doesn't mean it's good code, and you should put in some more effort if you want to properly learn a language. Trust me, I've learned the hard way!