# How to set size for vector of self-defined object?

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, initialization, default-constructor

I am trying to set size before using vector, but got error info:

> error c2512: 'EItem:EItem' : no appropriate default constructor available

```
// file.h
vector<EItem > *eL;

// file.cpp
eL = new vector<EItem>(100);
```

What do I need to provide in my own defined object `EItem`?

Comment: As the error message states, you need a default constructor. Do you have one?

Comment: how about the default ctor if I don't have one? thanks.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `new vector<EItem>(100, EItem(somestuff))` to initialize your vector with copies of a temporary `EItem`.

Answer (score 2):

As **your compiler is saying**, you have to define a default constructor for your `EItem` class :

in .h :

```
class EItem {
public:
    EItem(); // constructor

    // ...
};
```

in .cpp :

```
EItem::EItem() {}
```

Or all in one (in .h) :

```
class EItem {
public:
    EItem() {} // constructor

    // ...
};
```

It is the minimum. You can add some arguments to your class and initialize some attributes of your class in the constructor.

> In C++, default constructors are significant because they are automatically invoked in certain circumstances:
>
> - When an object value is declared with no argument list, e.g. `MyClass x;` or allocated dynamically with no argument list, e.g. `new MyClass` or `new MyClass();` the default constructor is used to initialize the object
> - When an array of objects is declared, e.g. `MyClass x[10];` or allocated dynamically, e.g. `new MyClass [10];` the default constructor is used to initialize all the elements
> - When a derived class constructor does not explicitly call the base class constructor in its initializer list, the default constructor for the base class is called
> - When a class constructor does not explicitly call the constructor of one of its object-valued fields in its initializer list, the default constructor for the field's class is called
> - **In the standard library, certain containers "fill in" values using the default constructor when the value is not given explicitly (ex : `vector<MyClass>(10);`), initializes the vector with 10 elements, which are filled with the default-constructed value of our type.**
>
> **In the above circumstances, it is an error if the class does not have a default constructor.**

There is some good answers on this thread too : [When do we need to have a default constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498937/when-do-we-need-to-have-a-default-constructor)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is pointing you to the right direction: your **class EItem does not have a default constructor** - hence you should supply one.

Quoted from [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/85-constructors/):

> What happens if we do not declare a default constructor and then
>   instantiate our class? The answer is that C++ will allocate space for
>   our class instance, but will not initialize the members of the class
>   (similar to what happens when you declare an int, double, or other
>   basic data type).

Without knowing the definition of your `EItem` class, a minimal example of implementing a default constructor is:

```
class EItem {
...
public:
    ...
    //this is a minimal default constructor
    EItem() {
        ...
        //initialize and set the values for any data members of the class here
        ...
    }
...
}
```

For more reading on this and more importantly *why* you should always supply one in your classes, see the following:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor

Answer (score 1):

The vector needs to know how much size an EItem takes up, since vector uses an array. A default constructor will be provided, if none other exist in the EItem class. Make sure you have the class defined and the constructor is public.

```
class EItem
{
 public:
   EItem();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class need to have a default constructor without parameters for it to be able to use a vector like that. If you can't have a default constructor then you need to make a vector of pointer to your class.